# system.xml admin menu - disable autocomplete in username password

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, system.xml

I have setup a module and my system.xml to enable admin menus. The issue is that the username and password fields are auto-populating which can potentially cause problems later down the track via a human error. Is it possible to put parameters in `system.xml` (and thereby render the input tag with `autocomplete="off"` to disable the autocomplete?

*EDIT*

This is not a question about browser behaviour. It is asking if it is possible to insert parameters into the `<input>` HTML when it is rendered via `system.xml` and/or AdminHTML.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no way to define this in `system.xml`. You would have to manipulate the generation of the form.

Also check this thread on StackOverflow stating that password managers (and also Chrome starting from v34) ignore this attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868299/is-autocomplete-off-compatible-with-all-modern-browsers

The most important quotes:

> Password managers now ignore the autocomplete attribute for password fields in the major browsers as of:
>
> - IE11
> - Firefox 30
> - Chrome 34
> - Safari seems to have an opt-in option to ignore them
>
> It should still work fine for disabling autocomplete on form fields, but no longer affects the password manager.

And:

> As of Chrome v34, autocomplete="off" is now ignored by default.
>
> This somewhat debatable feature can be disabled in the flags configuration by visiting chrome://flags
>
> http://news.softpedia.com/news/Chrome-34-Seeks-to-Save-All-Your-Passwords-436693.shtml

So I'd suggest to accept that users have to care about it themselves.